# how to apply unique function and transform and keep the complete columns in the data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-analysis

My goal here is to extract the count of rows in the data frame in which `for each PatienNumber and year and month` show the count of them and keep all the columns in the data frame.

This is the original data frame:

```
 PatientNumber           QT         Answer   Answerdate      year    month  dayofyear  count  formula
1        1          transferring     No      2017-03-03      2017       3         62      2.0   (1/3)
2        1          preparing food   No      2017-03-03      2017       3         62      2.0   (1/3)
3        1          medications      Yes     2017-03-03      2017       3         62      1.0   (1/3)
4        2          transferring     No      2006-10-05      2006       10        275    3.0    0   
5        2          preparing food   No      2006-10-05      2006       10        275    3.0    0
6        2          medications      No      2006-10-05      2006       10        275    3.0    0
7        2          transferring     Yes     2007-4-15       2007       4        105    2.0    2/3
8        2          preparing food   Yes     2007-4-15       2007       4        105    2.0   2/3
9        2          medications      No      2007-4-15       2007       4        105    1.0      2/3
10       2          transferring     Yes     2007-12-15      2007       12        345    1.0      1/3
11       2          preparing food   No      2007-12-15      2007       12       345    2.0    1/3
12       2          medications      No      2007-12-15      2007       12        345    2.0    1/3
13       2          transferring     Yes     2008-10-10      2008       10        280    1.0    (1/3)
14       2          preparing food   No      2008-10-10      2008       10        280    2.0    (1/3)
15       2          medications      No      2008-10-10      2008       10        280    2.0    (1/3)
16       3          medications      No      2008-10-10      2008       12        280    ……    ………..
```

so the desired output should be the same as this with one more column which shows the unique rows of [patientNumber, year, month]. for `patient number=1 shows 1` for the `PatientNumber= 2 shows 1 in year 2006, shows 2 in year 2007`

I applied this code:

```
data=data.groupby(['Clinic Number','year'])["month"].nunique().reset_index(name='counts')
```

the output of this code look like:

```
  Clinic Number  year  **counts**
0        494383  1999       1
1        494383  2000       2
2        494383  2001       1
3        494383  2002       1
4        494383  2003       1
```

the output **counts** is correct, except it does not keep the whole fields. I want the complete columns because later I have to do some calculation on them.

then I tried this code:

```
data['counts'] = data.groupby(['Clinic Number','year','month'])['month'].transform('count')
```

Again its not good because it does not show correct count. the output of this code is like this:

```
  Clinic Number Question Text Answer Text  ...    year month counts
1       3529933       bathing          No  ...    2011     1     10
2       3529933      dressing          No  ...    2011     1     10
3       3529933       feeding          No  ...    2011     1     10
4       3529933  housekeeping          No  ...    2011     1     10
5       3529933   medications          No  ...    2011     1     10
```

here counts should be `1` because for that patient and that year there is just one month.

Comment: What about `df['counts'] = df.groupby(['PatientNumber','year'])["month"].transform('nunique').reset_index(name='counts')`?

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks :) , but it raises wrong number of items passed 'counts'

Comment: @ScottBoston it works I just delete .reset_index(name='counts') in the end of line, it would be best if you answer so I can choose as the desired answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, the following modification to your code.

```
df['counts'] = df.groupby(['PatientNumber','year'])["month"].transform('nunique')
```

`transform` returns a series equal length to your original dataframe, therefore you can add this series into your dataframe as a column.